# after_commit fires but attribute changes are not captured

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

So I am encountering something a bit weird and need help

I have the following three models and their relationships are shown below

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :case_status
  has_one :application, :through => :case_status, :autosave => false 
  after_create :update_status

  def update_status
    self.case_status.update_attributes!({loan_case_id: update_case_status_id})
  end
end

class CaseStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: application
  has_many :assignments, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assignments,
                                :allow_destroy => true,
                                reject_if: proc { |attr| attr["lender_id"].blank? && attr["banker_id"].blank? }

  after_commit :catch_previous_changes,on: :update

  def catch_previous_changes
    self.previous_changes
  end
end

class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :case_status, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Basically, when an assignment is created, there is a method that updates the `loan_case_id` of that record on the case_status model but when the `self.versions` code is called, it is always empty.

But when I check the record on rails console, the data has been updated which leads me to understand that the `after_commit` call is being triggered but somewhat ahead of the thread that has the previous changes of the attribute `loan_case_id`.

Now I don't know how to debug this to know why this is happening because it only happens when d update is done via the after_create method. Any other form where the `loan_case_id` gets updated always has data when the `self.previous_changes` is called.

Answer (score 1):

You can not get any of the dirty changes from `after_commit`, you have to use `around_save`, similar to this:

```
class CaseStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  # all other code removed for brevity

  around_save :catch_previous_changes, on: :update

  def catch_previous_changes
    # see what attributes changed
    yield
    if persisted?
      # maybe do so other stuff if everything is ok
    end
  end
end
```